# Is asking about imaginary movies considered good questions here?

Tags: discussion

I have some ideas for future moviemaking. Can I discuss about them here?

Answer (score 15):

### **No, not on this site.**

This site, [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), is for questions and answers about *existing* works of science fiction or fantasy, either specific books/films/etc. or questions about the genre as a whole.

### **Maybe somewhere else, depending on the question.**

Your query is very vague, so it's hard to know exactly what you intend to ask. If it's a question about the *creation of fantasy worlds*, then [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) might be a good bet as other answerers have suggested. If it's a question about the *process of movie production*, then you might try [Movies & TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) (possibly - I'm not sure whether such questions are on-topic there, or if they like us apply a policy of "questions about existing works only") or [Video Production SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/) (whose scope I don't know at all).

Before asking on any site, though, you should **check their help centre** to see if your question is likely to be acceptable there or not. Every site has its own help centre page to explain which types of questions are on-topic and which are not.

- [Worldbuilding on-topic page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Movies & TV on-topic page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Video Production on-topic page](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: NOPE! ***NOT WORLDBUILDING!!!!!!*** We're very happy for the OP to ask questions about the worlds their movies are set in; but definitely not questions about scripts, screenplays, movie ideas, casting ideas, production resources or anything of that sort. I edited your answer accordingly.

Comment: @elemtilas I know that, but from the question here it was very unclear *what sort of question* the OP wanted to ask: whether it was about the process of movie making or about creating fictional worlds for a movie. In fact the reason I posted this answer was to provide *other* options than Worldbuilding, since for some reason everyone else here was just saying "go to Worldbuilding".

Comment: @elemtilas I think you've misunderstood why Rand included the link. It's their because _"If it's a question about the creation of fantasy worlds"_ and to link the OP to the on topic page so they can double check.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Perhaps so! (And for that I apologise.) However, we get these kinds of questions by the cartload over there. It's pretty clear that "moviemaking" ideas is about the making of movies, not the making of fictional worlds. Deffo off topic there! Somehow it should made clear why those links are in this answer, which is really specific to SF&F.

Comment: @elemtilas I'm not sure what else you want written in the answer, the entire paragraph before it is dedicated to why they are there.

Comment: @elemtilas I've written "*If it's a question about the creation of fantasy worlds, then Worldbuilding SE might be a good bet ...*" and then "*Before asking on any site, though, you should check their help centre to see if your question is likely to be acceptable there or not.*" Essentially, the link you removed is the part that should **stop** them from just posting on Worldbuilding without checking the scope.

Comment: Ideally, and this is just my opinion, WB wouldn't even be mentioned. Since it's placed under "maybe somewhere else", I believe this gives the impression that that somewhere else is SE's dumping ground, Worldbuilding.

Comment: @elemtilas Since all the other answers here recommend Worldbuilding and nothing else, I think it's worth having one that says "Worldbuilding *only if it's on-topic there*" and explains how to check whether it's on-topic there or not. Otherwise the OP can get the impression that Worldbuilding is definitely the right place for them to go.

Comment: Well, both of you have responded to me here; both of you can edit your answers! :) But at least you @Randal'Thor downvoted the third answer!

Comment: @elemtilas I downvoted both the other two answers. TLC's answer is better than EFH's, but still mentions only Worldbuilding without linking to that site's scope or help centre or anything.

Comment: @Randal'Thor FWIW I was going to add all the links then your answer came in that was better so left it be.

Comment: Re Movies & TV: Based on [these upvoted questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production?tab=Votes), I'm going to guess that you could ask about *common techniques* for making movies, but I'm not so sure they'd accept a question of the form "I'm trying to shoot X and common technique Y isn't going to work, so what should I do instead?"

Answer (score 6):

No, questions on this site should generally be about existing works of science fiction or fantasy. Depending on the question you could try Worldbuilding. However, I think it would need to be a specific question relating to building the world. Asking in general as in: would this film idea work? Wouldn’t be acceptable there or any SE site as far as I know.

Answer (score -2):

There is a whole Stack devoted to questions like the ones you want to ask called [worldbuilding:](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com)

> Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about worldbuilding.

Head on over and knock yourself out!

Comment: Why hasn't my reputation increased despite one up-vote?

Comment: @aminabzz Because this is the meta site (for Q&A *about* the site itself) and meta has no reputation system (the reputation displayed here is people's main-site rep).

Comment: Sorry, but I downvoted this answer because recommending the OP to Worldbuilding without caveats is quite likely to just lead to another site getting a poor or off-topic question.

Comment: No, actually Worldbuilding is ***nòt*** devoted to questions like this! The OP is discovering this fact at present.